# CSSTransition is not triggered

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-mountain-cjrte?file=/src/App.js

I'm trying to use CSSTransition from react-transition-group, for the first time, and it does not work :(

When I click on my button "learn more", I want to display the component "Expanded"(a div block) with a transition.

As of now, I don't get ANY animation of any kind. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using react-transition-group version 4.4.2.

Here is an extract of the container component:

```js
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';
import './styles.scss'

const MyComponent = ()=>{
  const [toggled, setToggle] = useState(false)
const handleClick=()=> {
setToggle(prevState=> !prevState)
}
return (
  <div>
        {toggled?
          <TransparentButton onClick={handleClick}>
          back
          </TransparentButton>
        :<TransparentButton onClick={handleClick>
          learn more
        </TransparentButton>   
}

    {toggled&&
      <CSSTransition in={toggled} timeout={200} classNames="my-node">
        <Expanded />
      </CSSTransition> 
      }

  </div>
)
```

./styles.scss:

```css
.my-node-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.my-node-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2000ms;
}
.my-node-exit {
  opacity: 1;
}
.my-node-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 200ms;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't see a problem with what you've shown us. It looks just like one of my implementations. Do you get any console errors? Could you work up a live demo somewhere?

Comment: Although my `-enter` rule has a CSS transition property on it, and my `-enter-active` rule has an animation property on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things:

1. You don't want to mount CSSTransition conditionally. So remove the `{toggled&&` that wraps it.
2. Add unmountOnExit prop to CSSTransition. CSSTransition will handle unmounting the component for you.

Check out their example: http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition

It's bit weird because their CodePen on their site is different than their example. They have `unmountOnExit` in the CodePen but not in the written part of the docs.

```
export default function App() {
  const [toggled, setToggle] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setToggle((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {toggled ? (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>back</button>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>learn more</button>
      )}

        <CSSTransition in={toggled} timeout={200} classNames="my-node" unmountOnExit>
          <div> TEST!</div>
        </CSSTransition>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The code below seems to work! will try on my actual project and confirm 
'<CSSTransition
        in={toggled}
        timeout={200}
        classNames="my-node"
        unmountOnExit
      >
        {toggled && <div> TEST!</div>}
      </CSSTransition>

Comment: @isherwood I fixed it in the code I posted, but I will edit to make that clearer.

Comment: @KaptainIglo you don't need `{toggled && <div> TEST!</div>}` - since `CSSTransition` is unmounting the component for you, that is a no-op. Just `<div> TEST!</div>` will do

Comment: THANK YOU both @Willow and isherwood. Works like a charm :) Well noted regarding the unnecessary conditional